# If $G$ is a non-trivial group in which every non-identity element has order $2$, then $|G|$ is even

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm doing some exercises on group-theory but got stuck in the following question:

> Let $G$ be a group such that for all $a \in G\setminus\{e\}$, $a^2 = e$. Prove that $|G|$ is even.

I tried using Lagrange's theorem but perhaps I still don't understand it fully for I was not capable of finishing it.

Could you shed some enlightenment on the matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about the group just containing one element, the identity?

Comment: You're right. I forget to write that a can't be e. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Ofc, $e^2 = e$.

Comment: it does not matter if you assume $a\not= e$, but you need to say that $G$ is nontrivial, otherwise as Chris noted the claim is false, even in its revised form (as for the trivial group it is vacuously true.)

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I understood. Thanks for taking the care.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Let $a\not=e$. If $a^2=e$, how many elements you got in the subgroup generated by $a$? Apply Lagrange......

NOTE: written at the same time as Myself's answer......

Comment: <a> = {a, a^2 = e, a^-1}, right?

Comment: Sure, and what is $a^{-1}$ in this case?

Comment: a-Ha, it is 'a' itself! I got it. Thanks for not telling me that right away!

Comment: @Marla: Ok, so you now see that it's enough to have just ONE element $a\not=e$ such that $a^2=e$ for $|G|$ to be even. Now you can try the following EXERCISE: Suppose $|G|$ even. Then there exists $a\not=e$ such that $a^2=e$.

Comment: @Andrea Mori: My intuition says: because there's $e \in G$, and because $|G|$ is even, there has to be at least one $a \in G\setminus\{e\}$, which $a^-1$ has to be in $G\setminus\{e\}$ already. I mean, $a^-1$ can't be a 'new member' -- has to already be a member in $G$. Otherwise, $|G|$ would be odd. Sorry if I kept you waiting. I appreciate your dedication very much! (Let's hope my dare with TeX doesn't turn into a mess)

Comment: I think you got the basic idea right, but you have expressed it a bit faulty. Basically, there has to exist an element $a \neq e$ which is it's own inverse, otherwise we can pair up all elements ($\neq e$) with their inverses, yielding an even number of elements. Add $e$ and you get an odd number. Thus there has to exist an element $a$ which is it's own inverse.

Comment: @Andrea Mori: To clarify my reasoning: If the set has an even number of elements, then my first mental picture is $\{a, a^-1, b, b^-1, c, c^-1, etc\}$. But then there's $e$, which $e^-1 = e$. So the "symmetry" is ruined and to keep the number of elements even, one has to sacrifice a 'new member' and turn some member already present into some other's inverse.


 @Calle: I arrived too late. The reasoning you expressed is the one I tried to convey.

Comment: Right, pair elements with their inverses. The identity $e$ is paired with itself and forms a singleton. Since there are an even number of elements overall there must be at least another singleton $\{a\}$, i.e. $a=a^{-1}$ or $a^2=e$. Note that this actually proves more: there is an odd number of elements of order $2$.

Comment: What we just proved is but the simplest case of CAUCHY's THEOREM: if $p$ is a prime number that divides $|G|$, then there exists $a\in G$, $a\not=e$, such that $a^p=e$.Mind that proving this is way more difficult!

Comment: @Marla, just a LaTeX tip: If you want to write $a^{-1}$, you need to write a^{-1} with { and } around the -1.

Answer (score 5):

One must obviously assume $G$ is a nontrivial finite group.

In this case $G$ has a subgroup $H = \{e,a\}$ of order 2, for any $a\in G$ that is not the unit. Therefore by Lagranges theorem the order of H divides the order of G, in other words: $|G|$ is even.

Comment: That's the straightest answer I can think of. But no need to look at H. If for all $a \in G \text{ such that } a \neq e$, $a^2 = e$, then they all are of order two. However, you don't need all of them to satisfy this. If one element $x$, not being $e$, satisfies $x^2 = e$, then its order divides the order of $G$, that's as simple as this. Thus the result.

Comment: Actually, proving that the order of an element divides the order of the group is done via the Lagrange theorem, resoning with the cyclic group generated by that element. So one way or another, you're using that group.
However, on an even more basic level you could state that $x\mapsto x\cdot a$ (where a satisfies $a^2=e$) is a involutory permutation on $G$ with no fixed points, hence the result. (Note that this is in fact equivalent to proving Lagranges thorem in this special case.)

Comment: Yeah sure. My remark was about my point of view on the clarity of exposure of the argument, not about the argument itself, since as I said that's exactly what I would have answered. I just thought adding H in there wasn't really necessary when just invoking the theorem, but this is equivalently correct as using it, of course.