# what is the meaning of this $ A=\bigcup_{x\in A}\{x,x^{-1}\}. $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

what is the  meaning of this  $
A=\bigcup_{x\in A}\{x,x^{-1}\}.
$ ?

I found the  this $A$ from here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/268877/557708

Comment: It states that "$A$ equals the set given by taking the union of every set of the form $\{x,x^{-1}\}$ where $x\in A$"

Comment: "The elements of $A$ pair up: if $x$ is in $A$ so is $x^{-1}$, and vice versa."

Comment: thanks @PeterForeman  now my  doubt is that  why does that imply that there are an odd number of elements of order $2$?

Comment: @jasmine Clearly since any x in A is distinct from its inverse there must be an odd number of elements in A. Then in the link you gave the group G where all these elements reside has even order. Naturally the identity is the only element of order not equal to 2 which isn't in A, so for the group G to have even order you would require an odd number of order 2 elements.

Comment: $|G|$ is even and $|A|$ is even so $|G\setminus A|$ is even but $G\setminus A$ contains exactly the identity element of order $1$ and every element of order $2$. Thus there must be an odd number of elements of order $2$.

Comment: thanks u so much @PeterForeman