# Let $G$ be a finite group of even order. Show that $\exists a\neq e, a=a^{-1}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification

> Let $G$ be  a finite group of even order. Show that $\exists a\neq e, a=a^{-1}.$

Suppose $\forall a\neq e,a\neq a^{-1}$ and define an equivalence reation on $G$ by $a\sim b$ if and only if $a=b$ or $a=b^{-1}$. Let $S=\{[a]:a\in G\}$ be the set of all equivalence classes. If $a=e, [e]=\{e\}$, and if $a\neq e, [a]=\{a,a^{-1}\}$ with $a\neq a^{-1}$. Then $G=\{e\}\cup(\bigcup\limits_{[a]\in S,[a]\neq [e]}\{a,a^{-1}\})$ and $|G|=2n+1$, a contradiction.

I am wondering if this proof is correct.

Comment: Your proof works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268873/a-finite-group-of-even-order-has-an-odd-number-of-elements-of-order-2

Comment: This looks like a job for [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).

Comment: Another very similar question: [Prove that any finite group $G$ of even order contains an element of order 2.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188519/prove-that-any-finite-group-g-of-even-order-contains-an-element-of-order-2?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. But you should say that the union is disjoint because it corresponds to the equivalence classes of your equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine.

Here's an alternative:

Since $\lvert G\rvert$ is even, it is divisible by two. Two is prime. Therefore, by Cauchy's theorem, there exists an $H\le G$ such that $\lvert H\rvert=2.$ Let $h\in H$ such that $h\neq e$. Then, by closure, $h^{-1}=h\in H\subseteq G$.